# CKeditor ( 4.3.3 ) and function ( onclick ) add HTML to editor and refreshing view

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, ckeditor

Hello just like in the subject. Im trying to insert some html code to my editor using external button. Its image html element. But i have idea how to do. I was reading some forum but there was no solution. Thank you for any help or sugestions. If there is needed editor instance please tell me how to get it.

```
<input type="button" onclick="addHtmlToEditor('myimage.jpg')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace('content_ckeditor');

function addHtmlToEditor(imgFile){
var htmltoeditor = "http://www.example.com/images/"+imgFile;
// some code inserting my html to ckeditor and update in fly :)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `insertHtml()` function. The documentation for it is here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml .

The Guide at the CKEditor docs site is actually  very good and I highly recommend that you read it as much as you can before starting to customize CKEditor. It's a very sophisticated software. The guide is at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide

What you want to do is create an image as a HTML string, grab an editor instance and then insert your HTML to that editor instance. Something like this should get you started (I didn't  test it).

```
function addHtmlToEditor(imgFile){
    var html = '<img src="http://www.example.com/images/' + imgFile + '" />';
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.content_ckeditor;
    editor.insertHTML(html);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the proper case insertHtml.Here the code may be it work for you

```js
function addHtmlToEditor(imgFile) {
    var html = '<img src="http://www.example.com/images/' + imgFile + '" />';
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.content_ckeditor;
    editor.insertHtml(html);
}
```

Comment: Please try to add some explanation with your code as well.